# How to find if an image has been edited in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Is it a good idea to use

```
$backup_sizes = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_backup_sizes', true);
```

to find if an image has been edited? Because WordPress creates a new record as postmeta.

Comment: Asking for opinions is off topic. [help/dont-ask] - But with respect to your question... Why wouldn't this be a good idea. `_wp_attachment_backup_sizes` is created when an image is edited, and only when an image is edited.